# Powershell v4 - Cannot capture XmlDocument Load() method error details

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Currently struggling to understand why my script isn't working as I have expected and so I thought I would take my problem to you :)

Essentially, I'm writing a program that will search for XML files on a system and iterate through them to figure out whether they are well-formed or not. To do this, I'm piping the output of a `Get-ChildItem` query to a `ForEach-Object` statement and recording the details in an ArrayList object to be parsed later. The script looks a little something like this;

```
// Variable declaration removed for brevity

Get-ChildItem -Path $dirFilePaths -Include "*.xml" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $tmpFile= $_;
    $tmpXml= New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument;

    try {
        $tmpXml.Load($tmpFile.FullName);
        $tmpValues= New-Object PSObject;

        $tmpValues | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File_Name" -Value $tmpFile.Name;
        $tmpValues | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File_Path" -Value $tmpFile.FullName;
        $tmpValues | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File_Status" -Value "OK";

        $arlFilesSuccess.Add($tmpValues)
        }
    catch {
        $tmpValues= New-Object PSObject;

        $tmpValues | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File_Name" -Value $tmpFile.Name;
        $tmpValues | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File_Path" -Value $tmpFile.FullName;
        $tmpValues | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File_Status" -Value "NOT OK";
        $tmpValues | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Error_Details" -Value $Error[-1].Exception;

        $arlFilesFailure.Add($tmpValues); 
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `$Error` variable doesn't actually contain any information on why the XML failed to load if the `$tmpXml.Load()` method fails due to a File problem. For instance, if I call a file on our system called "style.xml" into $tmpXml outside of the script I get the following error message from the PowerShell window;

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "The 'install-disabled' start tag on line 26 position 3 does not match the end tag of 'install'.
Line 26, position 105."
At line:1 char:1
+ $tmpXml.Load($arlFilesFailure[20].File_Path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

But when I type `$Error.count` into the PowerShell console, I get a value of `0` for some unknown reason. I've tried amending the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to `Stop` to force a terminating error; I've also tried writing the above script into a ScriptBlock and invoking it using `Invoke-Command` with the `ErrorVariable` CommonParameter set to a custom variable - still the command's error information is not captured and I can't figure out what is going on here!

Is this something to do with the fact that the Exception being encountered is a `MethodInvocationException` and that isn't classified as a terminating error? It's 'caught' in the Try/Catch statement so it must be a terminating error, no? Can anyone inform me of why these details aren't getting recorded in the global `$Error` variable (and also how I can retrieve that information)?

Comment: Inside the `catch` the variable `$_` represents the exception. You do not have to use `$Error`. But if you use `$Error` please remember that the most recent error is `$Error[0]`, i.e. the first in the list. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, `ForEach-Object` may cause some not clear errors, see https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/Cmdlets/ForEach-Object

Comment: @RomanKuzmin many thanks for this! Can you pop that in as an answer and I'll mark that as the Solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `catch` blocks the variable `$_` represents the current exception (as
`ErrorRecord`). You do not have to use `$Error`. But when you have to use
`$Error` remember that the most recent error is `$Error[0]`, i.e. the first in
the list.

Also, `ForEach-Object` may cause some not clear errors, see some examples:
[PowerShellTraps//Cmdlets/ForEach-Object](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/Cmdlets/ForEach-Object).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [PowerShell Community Extensions module](http://pscx.codeplex.com/releases/view/133199) here. It already has a Test-Xml function in it that will do what you're trying to do.